# Combine two select query into one sql query

Tags: mysql

Can I combine two mysql query below?

```
Select * from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_kpo_shop_order' and meta_value = 1

Select * from wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_kpo_ordered_item' and meta_value = 1233
```

I tried the following

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
            WHERE 
                ( meta_key = '_kpo_shop_order' AND meta_value = 1 ) OR 
                (meta_key = '_kpo_ordered_item'AND meta_value = 1233 );
```

the problem with the query above is the "OR" syntax. I want to make it "AND". Basically, I want only two rows or no rows at all.